# Using xslt in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xslt

Has c# .net any component for .xslt file? (to read,write,change)

I searched lots of sites but didnt find anything about that.

Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: This question may be helpful for you, as it deals with loading an XSLT file as part of a C# project. Hopefully, that should get you a bit closer to a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883598/access-an-xslt-file-as-resource-from-same-project

Answer (score 2):

This stackoverflow thread is similar to your question and you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278614/getting-variable-values-out-of-and-xslt-file).